# Scrollable Listview issue - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
class StoryUI extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Stories'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Georgy'),
            Storycard(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Storycard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
        return GestureDetector(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 8),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 10,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ClipRRect(
                      child: Image.asset(
                        news[index].image,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(16.0)),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Text(news[index].newsHeadline,
                          style: GoogleFonts.ubuntu(
                              fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => NewsDetails(news: news[index])));
            });
      },
      itemCount: news.length,
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying here to have a list of scrollable cards. I want space above the cards to add some text. SO I tried using column and have a text and Listview Bulider as children. But the emulator is showing blank screen.

When the StoryCard() is alone used as the body the output comes with widgets. I can't add anything above the Listview. Can someone help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWgWK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Expanded class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) or [Flexible class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) for the `ListView`.

> `ListView` requires a finite height for it's content.

With your current code, `ListView` is having infinite height, hence the error. `Expanded` or `Flexible` helps you to have the remaining space to be utilized for your child

**Solution**

```
class StoryUI extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Stories'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Georgy'),
            // here is the change
            Expanded(
               child: Storycard()
            )
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**Using Flexible**

```
class StoryUI extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Stories'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Georgy'),
            // here is the change
            Flexxible(
               fit: FlexFit.loose,
               child: Storycard()
            )
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```